# Blender is not running after download, how to make it run?

Tags: permissions, blender

I just downloaded the latest Blender version and it is not running when I double-click it or run it through the terminal. I'm the only person using the machine as currently the administrator in the distro. The only way to run the application is to call it as super user and even when I get it to open I cannot install certain purchased plugins due to the current permission configured Blender.

That is also true to some other apps that I had working in Linux and after updating the kernel last week it seems that the permissions got changed.

I'm somewhat new to Linux and don't want to mess with the permissions myself using `chmod` or `chown` as I learned it the hard way and had to re-install Linux.

That said, how can I permanently run Blender without having to do so as super user?

Comment: what did you download? was it a `.tar.xz` file? Did you follow [install instructions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/installing/linux.html)?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded a .tar.xz file from blender.org and followed the easiest method for the installation. Unpacked in a folder of my liking and double-click on the executable. It opens for 2 secs and closes. When call Blender through the terminal using sudo, it opens without any problems. The issue is also related to some pluings that I have. When I install one of them, Blender crashes. It seems that this issue is realted to the directory permission where the Blender executable is located. This problem started happening after I updated the Kernel. Now I cannot open it from any location.

Comment: you unpacked as a regular user, not as root?

Comment: Yes, as a regular user. Will try unpacking it with sudo in the terminal. Would that help?

Comment: no, then it WILL be owned by root, and you don't want that

Comment: which linux distro are you using

Comment: Ok, how should I proceed in this case? I'm using Mint.

Comment: no idea - if it was a distro I knew then I'd say things

Comment: why are you asking here ... ask at blender support

Comment: @jsotola I asked here because it seems that this issue is related to permissions on the folder where Blender is extracted. If you read my first message above you'll see that in this case, Blender only runs when called with sudo.

Comment: @Bravo all good, thank you for sharing some thoughts on this. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution by deleting the prefs folder in $Home/user/.config/Blender X.Y and the app is running again. Weirdly, without the need to call it with sudo after the folder got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the package manager of your GNU/Linux distribution first.
In Mint, try

```
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Your old blender config directory could give you trouble, so when in doubt move it to the side or delete it.

This goes for all software. In Linux, if you start downloading tar balls and such, stop and check if this is actually the recommended way to install that piece of software. The recommended way for **your distro**, not what the software's website says, at least as a rule of thumb.
Even if you have to first update your package repository to get the latest version of some package, this is usually much less trouble and comes with some other benefits.